# How to create several data sets, one for each value iterated in a for loop?

Tags: r

So I am mining data of occurences of fish species in Brazil, belonging to the "actinopterygii" group using the "rgbif" package, but since the number of occurences for that group is so high I can't retrieve them all at once.
With these two lines of code we can see there are 323200 occurrences:

```
#install.packages("rgbif")
library(rgbif)
actinopterygii<-name_backbone(name="Actinopterygii")
occ_count(taxonKey = actinopterygii$classKey,country="BR")
```

The thing is that the function that retrieves the occurences has a maximum limit of 2000 occurrences per retrieval:

```
actinopterygii_oc<-occ_search(taxonKey = actinopterygii$classKey,country="BR",limit=2000,start=0)
#the start argument refers to the index of the record we are starting at so we can page through all the results
```

I'm basically trying to avoid having to repeat this line 60 times and change the start value by 2000 every time, so I tried with a for loop but it's not working. I created an interval for the number of occurences, to perform the retrieval 2000 by 2000 at a time:

```
interval<-seq(from = 0, to = 323200, by = 2000)
for (value in interval){
  actinopterygii_oc<-occ_search(taxonKey = actinopterygii$classKey,country="BR",limit=2000,start=value)
}
```

The problem is this code is only modifying one single set of data everytime. So, is there any way I can create several sets of data, one for each value in the interval, while looping through the values in the interval?

I'm so sorry for how confusing this might be but I'm not able to express it any better, thank you in advance for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a for loop try `purrr::map` to get back a list of tibbles of 2,000 rows at a time.  I probably don't have to tell you this will take ***a long time***

```r
interval <- seq(from = 1, to = 323200, by = 2000)

list_of_tibbles <- 
   purrr::map(interval, 
              ~ occ_search(taxonKey = actinopterygii$classKey,
                           country="BR",
                           limit=2000, 
                           start= .x)
              )
```

I wasn't about to grab all your data but you get back output like

```r
[[1]]
Records found [323200] 
Records returned [2000] 
No. unique hierarchies [661] 
No. media records [2000] 
No. facets [0] 
Args [limit=2000, offset=1, taxonKey=204, country=BR, fields=all] 
# A tibble: 2,000 x 145
   key   scientificName decimalLatitude decimalLongitude issues datasetKey publishingOrgKey
   <chr> <chr>                    <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>           
 1 2550… Chaetodipteru…           -7.91            -34.8 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
 2 2550… Myrichthys oc…           -7.90            -34.8 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
 3 2550… Mugil curema …           -7.91            -34.8 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
 4 2550… Centropomus u…           -7.91            -34.8 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
 5 2550… Trachinotus c…           -7.91            -34.8 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
 6 2550… Phractocephal…           -3.18            -59.9 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
 7 2550… Diapterus aur…           -7.91            -34.8 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
 8 2550… Chaetodipteru…           -7.91            -34.8 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
 9 2550… Centropomus u…           -7.91            -34.8 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
10 2550… Calophysus ma…           -3.18            -59.9 cdrou… 50c9509d-… 28eb1a3f-1c15-4…
# … with 1,990 more rows, and 138 more variables: installationKey <chr>,
#   publishingCountry <chr>, protocol <chr>, lastCrawled <chr>, lastParsed <chr>,
#   crawlId <int>, extensions <chr>, basisOfRecord <chr>, occurrenceStatus <chr>,
#   taxonKey <int>, kingdomKey <int>, phylumKey <int>, classKey <int>, orderKey <int>,
#   familyKey <int>, genusKey <int>, speciesKey <int>, acceptedTaxonKey <int>,
#   acceptedScientificName <chr>, kingdom <chr>, phylum <chr>, order <chr>, family <chr>,
#   genus <chr>, species <chr>, genericName <chr>, specificEpithet <chr>, taxonRank <chr>,
#   taxonomicStatus <chr>, dateIdentified <chr>, coordinateUncertaintyInMeters <dbl>,
#   stateProvince <chr>, year <int>, month <int>, day <int>, eventDate <chr>,
#   modified <chr>, lastInterpreted <chr>, references <chr>, license <chr>,
#   identifiers <chr>, facts <chr>, relations <chr>, gadm.level0.gid <chr>,
#   gadm.level0.name <chr>, gadm.level1.gid <chr>, gadm.level1.name <chr>,
#   gadm.level2.gid <chr>, gadm.level2.name <chr>, gadm.level3.gid <chr>,
#   gadm.level3.name <chr>, geodeticDatum <chr>, class <chr>, countryCode <chr>,
#   recordedByIDs <chr>, identifiedByIDs <chr>, country <chr>, rightsHolder <chr>,
#   identifier <chr>, http...unknown.org.nick <chr>, verbatimEventDate <chr>,
#   datasetName <chr>, collectionCode <chr>, gbifID <chr>, verbatimLocality <chr>,
#   occurrenceID <chr>, taxonID <chr>, catalogNumber <chr>, recordedBy <chr>,
#   http...unknown.org.occurrenceDetails <chr>, institutionCode <chr>, rights <chr>,
#   eventTime <chr>, identifiedBy <chr>, identificationID <chr>, name <chr>,
#   occurrenceRemarks <chr>, gadm <chr>, informationWithheld <chr>,
#   recordedByIDs.type <chr>, recordedByIDs.value <chr>, individualCount <int>,
#   establishmentMeans <chr>, continent <chr>, organismQuantityType <chr>, habitat <chr>,
#   http...rs.tdwg.org.dwc.terms.organismQuantity <chr>,
#   georeferenceVerificationStatus <chr>, verbatimSRS <chr>, verbatimCoordinateSystem <chr>,
#   county <chr>, locality <chr>, taxonRemarks <chr>, preparations <chr>, disposition <chr>,
#   vernacularName <chr>, organismName <chr>, fieldNotes <chr>, originalNameUsage <chr>,
#   http...rs.tdwg.org.dwc.terms.organismQuantityType <chr>, …
```

You'll notice that what you get back has not only the data but other meta data.  To glue it all the `data` back together into one big dataframe another `map`

```r
glued_data <- 
   purrr::map(list_of_tibbles, "data") %>% 
   bind_rows()

dim(glued_data)
[1] 10000   162
```

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate the sets of data in a list like so:

```
interval<-seq(from = 0, to = 323200, by = 2000)
actinopterygii_oc <- list()

for (i in 1:length(interval)){
  value <- interval[i]
  actinopterygii_oc[[i]] <- occ_search(taxonKey = actinopterygii$classKey,country="BR",limit=2000,start=value)
}
```

and then combine them using for example `dplyr::bind_rows(actinopterygii_oc)`.